# Why isn't PHP function call working as expected

Tags: php

I have PHP file which I include after my index  file is loaded, I call a function at some point within that php file , everything goes fine up uptil now

But when the called function tries to call another function within the same php file the function call never seems to happen,here is what I am talking about :

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 global $logger;
 $logger->info("inside user.php");

//require_once("./vendor/wixel/gump/gump.class.php");
require_once("./bizDataLayer/gameBizData.php");
require "./bizDataLayer/dbInfoPS.inc";//to use we need to put in: global $mysqli;
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 * 
 * @global type $logger
 * @param type $d API data as JSON
 * @param type $ip user IP address
 * @param type $token user token
 */
function registerUser($d, $ip, $token) {

    global $logger;
    $logger->debug("insider registerUser() function");

    //Check if data is valid
    $data=validateData($d);  /////////////////////This call seems to never work

    if(!$data){
        $errorMsg = array(
                'error' =>'Data send is invalid.'
            );
            $logger->info("user exist error as".$errorMsg);
            return json_encode($errorMsg);
    }



    $logger->debug("The data has been validated -- about to insert into DB");

    // Prepared data for the database use
    // Hash password
    $password_hash = password_hash($validated_data['password1'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    $logger->debug("Hashed password: '".$password_hash."'");


    $userData = array(
        'firstName' => $data['firstName'],
        'lastName' => $data['lastName'],
        'email' => $data['email'],

        'password' => $password_hash,
        'status' => 1,
        'registration_date' => date('Y-m-d G:i:s')
    );




    return insertUser($userData);

}
//this is the function I call
function validateData($data){
    $logger->debug("insider validateDatar() function");  //loggin out if the function is call ,but it is not

    $gump = new GUMP();
   // $logger->info("gump:".$gump);
    $data = $gump->sanitize($data); // You don't have to sanitize, but it's safest to do so.

    $gump->validation_rules(array(
        'firstName'    => 'required|alpha_numeric|max_len,100|min_len,6',
        'lastName'    => 'required|max_len,100|min_len,6',
        'email'       => 'required|valid_email',
        'password'      => 'required|max_len,100|min_len,6',
        'status' => 'required|integer'
    ));

    $gump->filter_rules(array(
        'firstName'    => 'required|alpha_numeric|max_len,100|min_len,6',
        'lastName'    => 'required|max_len,100|min_len,6',
        'email'       => 'required|valid_email',
        'password'      => 'required|max_len,100|min_len,6',
        'status' => 'required|integer'
    ));

    $validated_data = $gump->run($data);

    if($validated_data === false) {
        return false;
    } 
    else {
        return $validated_data;
    }
```

}

When I check my log the function validateData()' seem like it is never called. I don't seem to understand why .

Here is the complete project just in case :

https://github.com/Snedden/webGame.git

Comment: Why do you think it's never called?

Comment: Nothing gets logged inside your `validateData` function because `$logger` doesn't exist in its scope. Had you set error_reporting to E_ALL as you always should in development, PHP would notice you about it.

Comment: yes My bad ,It seem my function fails here and doesn't return anything. trying to find what wrong with my function now